# Find the primitive of a real function

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that this integral should be simple but I am really struggling to understand how to get in **2arcsecx + c** response. I managed to solve the problem at this point and my difficulty is in relation to this square root:

$$
\int\sqrt{\frac{4}{x^4-x^2}}dx = \int\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^4 - x^2}}dx = 2\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4 - x^2}}
$$

Comment: Let $x=\sec t$. All collapses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by writing $x^4 - x^2 = x^2 (x^2 - 1)$.  Take the $x^2$ outside the square root.  Then use the substitution $x = \sec(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let (in the Euler spirit)
$$
u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2}},
$$
and you will get
$$
-2\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du.
$$
The result of course becomes
$$
-2\arctan\Bigl(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2}}\Bigr)+C.
$$
Now, that is not in the final form you were looking for, and it can be simplified a bit, but anyways...